# What time period determines the long-term capital gains tax for foreign individuals in Canada?

Tags: canada, capital-gains-tax, capital-gain, canada-revenue-agency

Let's say I am either a resident of the US or Mexico. If I have a stock I have held for more than 12 months while abroad, and then sell it within the first week of my arrival in Canada, would it be considered a short-term or long-term sale for capital gain tax purposes? Does the holding period for foreign individuals begin from the time of purchase or from their time of arrival in a new country?

Comment: Canada doesn't make a distinction between short and long-term capital gains. Are you asking about the U.S. treatment?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Oh really? I didn't know this. I thought Canada also had a system of short-term vs long-term capital gains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Inclusion Rate

In Canada, there is no distinction between short-term and long-term capital gains tax. Instead, they have something called the [inclusion rate](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/individuals/topics/about-your-tax-return/tax-return/completing-a-tax-return/personal-income/line-12700-capital-gains/you-calculate-your-capital-gain-loss/inclusion-rates-previous-years.html) when calculating your taxable income based on capital gains. As of 2023, the inclusion rate is 50%, meaning only half of your capital gains are included when computing your taxable income.

For example, if you have $100,000 CAD in capital gains, applying the 50% inclusion rate would result in $50,000 CAD of taxable income.

### Business income vs Capital income

Another thing that is crucial to note is that Canada distinguishes between income derived from capital and income derived from business. The 50% inclusion rate applies only to the former.

In Canada, [day trading falls under the category of business income](https://www.td.com/ca/en/investing/direct-investing/articles/day-trading#:%7E:text=Your%20income%20from%20day%20trading,as%20are%20certain%20related%20expenses). Consequently, if you engage in frequent day trading, you won't be eligible for the 50% inclusion rate. Instead, you'll have to declare the entire amount of capital gains (100%) as taxable income.